# Modal View not being removed from stack

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am creating a modal view which is opened using the following code

```
[[self navigationController] presentModalViewController:registrationController animated:NO];
```

And until recently the following code was used to hide it on a button press

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

However for some reason that line is no longer removing the view and no errors are presented.

I have also tried

```
[self.view removeFromSuperView];
```

But that just leaves me with a completely white screen

Any suggestions on how I go about debugging this issue will be great as Im stumped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your controller is a subclass of `UIViewController`, then inside the modal view controller:

```
[self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: unfortunately that has made no difference either, it just doesnt want to remove from the stack :(

Answer (score 1):

I worked out the problem I was updating the Navigation Controller after loading the modal in order to change the style, changing the order solved the problem

Comment: actually yours is a valid answer to the question, but my situation is not completely outlined in the question so I feel yours is more appropriate, thanks for the honesty though

Comment: re: honesty: one has to sleep at night :)